# How to initialize ReactWOW in page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I am working on a project based on React.js & for animation, I have used [ReactWOW npm package](https://github.com/skyvow/react-wow) for wow animation such as

```
import ReactWOW from 'react-wow';

<ReactWOW delay='0.6s' animation='fadeInDown'>
   <img src={require('/board.png')} alt="board" />
</ReactWOW>
```

it works but after scroll down & I want to work after page loads without scrolling.

What can I do now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know of is to simulate a scroll yourself.

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1);
```

Let me know if you have a better solution!